# ListBox is selecting more than one item when it is being dragged

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, listbox, radio-button

I have a ListBox with RadioButton inside it of the same GroupName.

Like so:

```
<ListBox x:Name="AnswerListBox" DataContext="{Binding .}" ItemsSource="{Binding Answers}" Width="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:spriteToggleButton DataContext="{Binding .}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding text}" Selected="{Binding selected}" Sprites="{Binding Path=DataContext.UISprites, ElementName=questionField}" IsChecked="{Binding selected, Mode=TwoWay}" GroupName="{Binding Path=DataContext.QuestionTitle, ElementName=questionField}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

When I click on a RadioButton it will unselect another in that group, this is fine.

But when I do a swipe down on the ListBox it will select more than one RadioButton which is an unwanted behavior.

There might be more than one way of changing that behavior.

1. I don't need it to scroll up and down the list as I will only show as many items as will fit on screen. so maybe that behavior can be disabled.
2. Maybe a callback could incur when the ListBox is scrolled and something could disable selection when dragging in being done.
3. the DataContext to the listbox is of List<> so is there a way to change the setter of my Selected variable in my List<> so that it unsets the other values in that list.

Comment: The DataContext="{Binding .}" is completely unnecessary. The DataContext defaults to inheriting it from the parent element, or template.

Comment: Ok thanks, removing will make my code cleaner. but i still have that issue i've mentioned. Thanks for the tip though. It's left over code from when nothing worked with some of my DependencyProperties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Set `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility` to "Disabled" on the `ListBox` element.
2. In the `SelectionChanged` event, set the `SelectedIndex` to -1
3. You could clear all the other values in the `ItemsSource` in the `SelectionChanged` event.

Comment: i'll try #1, #2 not sure, wouldn't that disable valid clicks not just drag-clicks. #3 do you mean sender.ItemsSource?

Comment: Depends how you set your stuff up, but most likely, yes.

Comment: actually the solution was to change the ClickMode to "press", it makes sense now because by dragging and letting go i'm releasing on more that one item.